# Gauss curvature of $x^4-x^2+y^2+z^2=a$

Tags: differential-geometry

Let $S_a=\{(x,y,z) \in \mathbb R^3 \mid x^4-x^2+y^2+z^2=a\}$

1. Give the set $A$ of $a$'s for which $S_a$ is a regular surface.

2. Find $a \in A$ for which the Gauss curvature of $S_a$ is positive everywhere.


I guess, if $a \neq -\frac{1}{4}$ or 0, $S_a$ is regular.

Is it true?

and how I can solve 2? By direct calculation?

Comment: Can you also share with us how you find $a\neq \frac 14$?

Comment: I guess $(1/\sqrt{2},0,0)$ is a critical point. So -$\frac{1}{4}$ is a critical value

Comment: If you solve $4x^3 - 2x = 0$, there should be three solutions.

Comment: @JohnMa $x=\pm 1/\sqrt{2}$ or 0, Then?

Comment: Cross-linking with the subsequent question [condition of being regular surface](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1488748/condition-of-being-regular-surface), which was asked by a different user with an identical gravitar (ahem).