# condition of being regular surface

Tags: differential-geometry

Let $S_a$ be the surface given by $x^4-x^2+y^2+z^2=a$
Let $F=x^4-x^2+y^2+z^2$
$(F_x,F_y,F_z)=0$ when $x=0$ or $ \pm \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$
So I guess $S_a$ is regular when $a \ne 0$ and $-\frac{1}{4}$

Then How about $a = 0$ or $-\frac{1}{4}$? $S_a$ fails to be regular? How I know?

Comment: Cross-linking with the earlier question [Gauss curvature of $x^4−x^2+y^2+z^2=a$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1487079/gauss-curvature-of-x4-x2y2z2-a), which was asked by a different user with an identical gravitar (ahem), and deleting my answer.